# How can I add one more storage_allowed_location in Snowflake storage integration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created one Snowflake storage integration as follow:

```
create or replace storage integration s3_int
    type = external_stage
    storage_provider = s3
    enabled = TRUE
    storage_aws_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::xxx'
    storage_allowed_locations = ('S3://location1', 
                                 's3://location2',
                                 's3://location4',
                                 's3://location5',
                                 's3://location6',
                                 's3://location7',
                                 's3://location8');
```

Now I like to add 2 more locations, I know that I can use SET `storage_allowed_locations` like following:

```
ALTER STORAGE INTEGRATION s3_int 
SET storage_allowed_locations = ('S3://location1', 
                                 's3://location2',
                                 's3://location4',
                                 's3://location5',
                                 's3://location6',
                                 's3://location7',
                                 's3://location8',
                                 's3://location9',
                                 's3://location10');
```

But the problem is, along the time I will have more and more locations to add in this `storage_allowed_location` list. Do I always have to give the whole list of locations and add the new locations in the end of it? It will become super long and annoying in the end. Do you know if there is other ways to add/append the new location in existing location list?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, yes, the storage locations have to be added along with the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I created a stored procedure to address this problem specifically, as it has caused me headaches in the past.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_ALLOWED_STORAGE_LOCATION (storage_integration_name text, new_location text)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE
 EXISTING_LOCATIONS text;
 FINAL_LOCATIONS text;
 FINAL_LOCATIONS_STR text;
 ALTER_SQL text;
BEGIN

 --get existing storage locations and store them in variable
 DESCRIBE STORAGE INTEGRATION IDENTIFIER(:storage_integration_name);
 SELECT existing_vals
 INTO EXISTING_LOCATIONS
 FROM ( SELECT "property_value" AS existing_vals
        FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
        WHERE "property" = 'STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS'
        );

-- remove existing instances of the new_location if it's already present
FINAL_LOCATIONS := (SELECT REPLACE(:EXISTING_LOCATIONS, LOWER(:new_location) || ',', '')); --remove if it's the first item in the list
FINAL_LOCATIONS := (SELECT REPLACE(:FINAL_LOCATIONS, ',' || LOWER(:new_location), '')); --remove if it's in the list anywhere else

-- add new_location to the list
FINAL_LOCATIONS := (SELECT LOWER(:FINAL_LOCATIONS) || ',' || LOWER(:new_location));

--format the list of final locations as it would be in a SQL statement, ie: ('first_item','second_item')
FINAL_LOCATIONS_STR := (SELECT '(''' || REPLACE(:FINAL_LOCATIONS, ',', ''',''') || ''')');

-- construct the SQL statement to alter the storage integration
ALTER_SQL :=  (SELECT ' ALTER STORAGE INTEGRATION ' ||  :storage_integration_name || ' SET storage_allowed_locations = ' || LOWER(:FINAL_LOCATIONS_STR) || ';') ;

-- execute the sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ALTER_SQL;

RETURN ALTER_SQL;
END;
$$;
```

Here's an example of it in use:

```
CALL ADD_ALLOWED_STORAGE_LOCATION('my_storage_integration', 's3://my-s3-url/');
```

It is idempotent, so executing it multiple times with the same arguments will still result in the new location only being added once.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is:

```
STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('*')
```

From the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration#examples) all sub paths in "ALLOWED_STORAGE_LOCATIONS" will inherit permissions from all allowed locations. So, be aware that any path in this account will be accessible from this integration that isn't explicitly called out in the "BLOCKED_STORAGE_LOCATIONS" parameter.

For security purposes, if you're using this storage account for other things, you may want to create a specific bucket for this integration and point your process to the bucket instead of using a wildcard at the account level. No need for wildcard (*) at bucket level.

like:

```
STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('S3://bucket_for_this_specific_integration/')
```